# Batch Escape Percent sign

Tags: batch-file, escaping, environment-variables

Hi Guys having a really hard time getting an environmental variable piped to clip.exe, in a regular command prompt it works but once in batch file it fails. I have tried escaping with double `%%` and a few other tricks. Nothing seems to work.

I am trying to pipe the output of the citrix environmental variable `%clientname%` to clip.exe like the following:

```
@echo off
echo %clientname% | clip
```

Comment: wtf why are you talking abut escaping?  btw you can escape with ^%  No idea why echo %blah% isn't working for you. I suggest you troubleshoot. like try other variables.

Comment: I have been troubleshooting, this isnt just some variable that I have set, this is one that is created only in citrix sessions. Like I said this works from a command line but once run in a batch it does not. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: Do you want to echo the literal %name% or the contents of the variable?  Your code above will be including a trailing space in both situations.

Comment: The contents of the variable is what I am after. I am ok with the trailing space.

Comment: Then what happens when you try that code you have shown?  Place `echo."%clientname%"` on the line above - does it echo what you expect?  The quotes will show you if the variable is empty.

Comment: If I run what I have above I end up with "ECHO is on." in clipboard. I just ran what you posted and it ends up with just two quotes.

Comment: then it's acting like there is no such variable. are you sure you spelt the variable name right?  try set clientna  see if the clientname variable appears if not, try set cl  Try creating a var called clientname2  try echoing it. view the variables with set | more ot set cli i.e. troubleshoting. See if it shows as set when within a batch file

Comment: From command prompt on the client I run:
Set Clientname and the output is as expected:
CLIENTNAME=ENROLL-02

(enroll is the name of the local machine which is correct)

Comment: do it from batch file, as that is where the issue is

Comment: Your variable is empty - and the reason might be because you are setting the variable in some other program, Citrix? Or you typo'd the name.

Comment: Actually `echo %%clientname%%| clip` works, but only if variable `clientname` is undefined; if it could be defined, use `echo %%^^clientname%%| clip` instead (assuming there is no variable named `^clientname`)…

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `^` sign to escape the `%` char in command line:

```
C:\> echo ^%clientname^%
```

But you need to use the `%` sign to escape a `%` symbol in a batch file:

```
@echo %%clientname%%
```

Comment: You can't escape a percent sign with a caret, in a batch file you can escape it with a second `%`